# LWC Jest Test showing show error in Azure Devops Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, jestjs, salesforce, lwc, sfdx

When i running Jest test for LWC in azure pipelines i got strange error

```
Cannot find module 'c/myComponent' from 'force-app/main/default/lwc/myComponent/__tests__/myComponent.test.js'

  1 | import { createElement } from 'lwc';
> 2 | import myComponent from 'c/myComponent';
    | ^
  3 | import fetchTopics from '@salesforce/apex/MyComponentController.getAllContentTopics';
  4 |
  5 | const mockGetTopics = require('./data/getTopics.json');

  at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (force-app/main/default/lwc/myComponent/__tests__/myComponent.test.js:2:1)
```

This is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  ...jestConfig,
  coverageReporters: ['clover', 'json', 'text', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ['/.localdevserver'],
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>"],
  reporters: [
    'default',
    [
      'jest-junit',
      {
        outputDirectory: 'tests',
        outputName: 'test-results-lwc.xml'
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

In Azure Devops im running jest test on ubuntu-latest image
Node.js is 19.9.0 and Npm is in 9.6.3 version

When i run same test and same config i got 100% coverage and all tests are passed
What can be diff between this test run ?

Comment: Could you please add a few more details like your pipeline yaml file and the LWC test file

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn’t need at the modulePaths proprieties unless you have distinct path. Also it looks like you are missing the import in the config file.

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
```